# use response data in columndef datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using datatable jquery.I want to use Sr_no in data-id of td tag but How to get data of Sr_no.

or you can say that I want particular data from data reponse

I have highlighted in code

```
$("#fir").dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,

    "sAjaxSource": "paid.php",
    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumns": [

        {"mData": "Sr_no"}, <------ I dont want to add this column in table but I want to use value
        {"mData": "Category_Name"},
        {"mData": "Vendor_Name"},
        {"mData": "date"},
        {"mData": "Price"},
        {"mData": "Payment_Mode"},
        {"mData": "remark"},
        {"mData": "edit"},
        {"mData": "cancel"}
    ],
    'columnDefs': [
        {
           'targets': 1,
           'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
               console.log(row,col);
              $(td).attr('data-id',Sr_no);  <----------------
           }
        }

     ]

});
```

Comment: What version of DataTable are you using?

Comment: datatable version --1.11.5

Comment: I just need to Sr_no in data-id attribute so I can identify using selector but I dont know how to use response data in td data-id attribute

Comment: If you want this to make changes to the rendered HTML, then you're probably not using datatables fully.   eg clicking a button on a datatable should be able to give you all the *data* for that row via the datatables api, not just what's been rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rowData.Sr_no` to get the value of `Sr_no` for each row. Change `targets: 1` to

```
{
   'targets': 1,
   'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
       console.log(row,col);
      $(td).attr('data-id', rowData.Sr_no);
   }
}
```